# How to get the screen coordinate of specific string in python?

Tags: python, string

I want to get the screen coordinate of specific string.
for example.
You can find 'example' key at least one on this web-page(previous row).
I want to get this key coordinate(x,y) on screen. Strictly speaking,the coordinates of the first letter of the key.
How to achieve this work in python?
thanks.

Comment: What you done so far ?

Comment: Search similar work and some module that is likely to acquire screen output information.  but I can't find.

Comment: You can use selenium foe this though it only helps to locate the string webelement. (elem.location)

Comment: thank you SuniIT. I'll try with selenium.